# Visual C++ Literal 0 Integer

Tags: c++-cli

I current have 0U as a parameter for a function and it results in the "warning C4965: implicit box of integer 0; use nullptr or explicit cast." This warning is assuming that I'm using `0U` to mean `nullptr`; however, I'm trying to actually use `0U` as an unsigned zero value integer. All help I've found suggests how to cast the `0U` to `nullptr` but not vica versa. Advice?

```
String::Format("{0}", 0U);
```

Comment: Can you add the function declaration, and the calling line?

Comment: String::Format("{0}", 0U);

Comment: How do you expect `0U` to display/format differently from `0`, and why not just use `"0"`? (the string representation of `0` should not be changing).

Comment: Putting `String::Format("{0}", 0U);` or `String::Format("{0}", 0);` both give this warning. I'd like to understand how to correctly avoid the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String::Format takes arguments of type object for the arguments after the format string (the first argument). Since 0 or 0U are both structs they will be implicitly boxed to be of type object since that is what the type of the argument is. In your case the implicit boxing isn't bad since the code is going to have to box it anyway and for you to explicitly box it will require more code on your part.

Your example is somewhat odd considering that normally you would just do `"0"` rather than `String::Format("{0}", 0)`. Typically you have a parameter to reference and to get around the implicit box warning you would call `ToString` on it (which is what String::Format will do internally anyway) to avoid the extra boxing.

So this below should give the warning because you are passing a struct to an argument that expects an object so the struct will get implicitly boxed

```
int x = 0;
String::Format("{0}", x);
```

To get rid of the implicit boxing I normally do this

```
int x = 0;
String::Format("{0}", x.ToString());
```

This passes a String to the function and a string is a reference type so it doesn't need to be boxed. Avoiding the implicit boxing in the case I gave above does help very slightly performance wise since you would avoid the implicit boxing operation.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense now considering the int is a struct and the function wants an object. That's the key I needed. In reality, I'm doing formatting and have several arguments to String::Format. The example is a striped down version of my actual code just to demonstrate the root problem.

Comment: No problem. I am glad I could help.